# <input> tag validation for URL

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate an URL using JavaScript, but for some reason it's not working. When someone has not entered any URL, it shows message like:

> Please enter valid URL.(i.e. http://)

I am trying to fix it, but can't make it working.

Is there any trick in HTML5 that allows to validate an URL?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#contactInfos").validate( 
 { onfocusout: false, rules: { 
       phone: { number:true }, 
       zipcode: { number:true }, 
       website: {    url:true    } 
 }, 
     messages: { phone: { number:"please enter digit only" }, 
     zipcode: { number:"Plese enter digit only"  }, 
     website: { url: "Please enter valid URL.(i.e. http://)"     } 
   } 

});
```

Validate method for an URL:

```
url: function(value, element) {
      values=value.split(',');
      for (x in values)
      {
          temp=values[x].trim();
  temp1=this.optional(element) || /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(temp);

      if(temp1!=true)
      {
        return false;
      }
      }
       return true;
},
```

Comment: this is the code
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#contactInfos").validate(
  {
 onfocusout: false,
    rules:
    {
      phone:
      {
        number:true
      },
   zipcode:
   {
     number:true
   },
   website:
 { 
  url:true 
 }
    },
    messages:
    { 
      phone:
      {
        number:"please enter digit only"
      },
   zipcode:
   {
     number:"Plese enter digit only"   
   },
   website:
  {
   url: "Please enter valid URL.(i.e. http://)" 
  }
    }
  });

i have used jquery for it, but not working :(

Comment: You've called a method name validate. Where's the code for that method? I've also edited your post to include the code you pasted above. Also the code you pasted above would produce errors in the current format.

Comment: @PrinceBijvani: it will be easiest for someone here to help you if you set up a jsFiddle (jsfiddle.com) that shows your attempt and problem.

Comment: @TommyBs i have edited it above

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen jsfiddle.com is not working :(

Comment: Oops... my bad: jsFiddle.net.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In html5 you can use the tag input type="url":

```
<input type="url" />
```

you can use your own pattern too:

```
<input type="url" pattern="https?://.+" required />
```

In the paper Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax [RFC3986] http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt the regular expression for a URI is:

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

> For example, matching the above expression to
>
> ```
>   http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
> ```
>
> results in the following subexpression matches:
>
> ```
>   $1 = http:
>   $2 = http
>   $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
>   $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
>   $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
>   $6 = <undefined>
>   $7 = <undefined>
>   $8 = #Related
>   $9 = Related
> ```

Comment: i wnat to make http part optional

Comment: I'm pretty sure it *is* optional.

Comment: Since this is high in the search results for this problem and two of these comments confused me here's an update/clarification based on my research:

1. [The pattern attribute IS supported by url type inputs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.url.html)

2. "http" is not optional by default (at least in some browsers - in Chrome and Firefox it is not)

Comment: To make http part optional follow this regexp
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42619368/2637620

Answer (score 2):

Does it make sense that the url is valid without a protocol?

For instance, currently `http://google.com` is a valid url, while `google.com` is not.

Similarly, `http://localhost` is a valid url, while `localhost` is not a valid url.