# I used type= url in html , textbox is accepting http://////////, i need it accept only two slashes. what should i do?

Tags: javascript, html

I used type= url in html , textbox is accepting `http://////////`, i need it accept only two slashes. what should i do?

**HTML :**

```
<input type="url"  class="textBoxStyle" name="ServerUrl" id="TextBoxBuildServerUrl" required />
```

Comment: You might want to check this out:http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp
You can validate the input using the following regex:
"^(https?:\\/\\/)?([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6})([\\/\\w \\.-]*)*\\/?$"

Comment: You will probably find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820477/html5-input-tag-validation-for-url

Comment: @anaBad i used ur pattern but it is rejecting my url . url is "(http://dj-5698.olw.com:8000/code)"

Comment: @nive Check the answers

Answer (score 0):

Using whichever method you want, you can validate the input URL with the following regex to make sure that the user has given you a valid URL. This solution may be better long term because not only will it deny multiple slashes as expressed in your original question, but it will also reject any other invalid URL.

```
'^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$'
```

Make sure to include `iu` modifiers to ignore case and treat the string as UTF-16 formatting. I would put this into whatever script you're using to validate the form (i.e. a PHP `POST` method).

Comment: Updated pattern. Should no longer have that issue.

Comment: still not working. it still accepts http://///. i want pattern which should only accepts http:// in the start

Comment: Please post your implementation code in your post because my implementation of this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to go with the RegEx approach to validate your URLs, I suggest you check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294):

```
var re_weburl = new RegExp(
    "^" +
    // protocol identifier
    "(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)" +
    // user:pass authentication
    "(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?" +
    "(?:" +
      // IP address exclusion
      // private & local networks
      "(?!(?:10|127)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})" +
      "(?!(?:169\\.254|192\\.168)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})" +
      "(?!172\\.(?:1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})" +
      // IP address dotted notation octets
      // excludes loopback network 0.0.0.0
      // excludes reserved space >= 224.0.0.0
      // excludes network & broacast addresses
      // (first & last IP address of each class)
      "(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])" +
      "(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}" +
      "(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))" +
    "|" +
      // host name
      "(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)" +
      // domain name
      "(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*" +
      // TLD identifier
      "(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,}))" +
      // TLD may end with dot
      "\\.?" +
    ")" +
    // port number
    "(?::\\d{2,5})?" +
    // resource path
    "(?:[/?#]\\S*)?" +
    "$", "i"
);
```

The comments above each section of the RegEx can help you modify it to parse URLs the way you want.