# how to create patterns in TextBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pattern-matching

**Notes :** i tired all questions & answer related this topic. Like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820477/html5-input-tag-validation-for-url)

I use simple Form  Use **URL TextBox** i use **patterns**  `pattern="https?://.+"` that perfect work.

**I want to allow Text (small & uppercase)  Like**

```
1. www.test.com
2. https://www.test.com
3. https://test.com
4. WWW.TEST.COM
5. HTTPS://WWW.TEST.COM*
6. HTTP://TEST.COM
```

**i tried Code  :**

```
<input name="website" id="website" type="text" class="Custom_textbox"  pattern="https?://.+"/>
```

**Notes:** Only Using pattern try to solve my problem. **not other script**

**My code** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ef0u3vbc/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an alternation like this:

```
pattern="(www\.|https?://).+"
         ^     ^         ^
```

A case-insensitive version:

```
pattern="([wW][wW][wW]\.|[hH][tT][tT][Pp][sS]?://).+"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nEWC4/1). Note that the case insensitive version can be shortened with the help of limiting quantifiers: `pattern="([wW]{3}\.|[hH][tT]{2}[Pp][sS]?://).+"`.

It will accept any input starting with `www.` or `http://` or `https://`.

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
  <input name="website" id="website" type="text" class="Custom_textbox"
     pattern="([wW][wW][wW]\.|[hH][tT][tT][Pp][sS]?://).+" 
     title="Please valid url" required/>
  <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: thanks For Answer. but i Add Text like WWW.TEST.COM then error are there

Comment: Yes, because regex is by default case sensitive and you cannot use modifiers in the HTML5 pattern attribute. You will have to use character classes.

Comment: awesome .Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew