# Regex for website or url validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I know this is so common question & there are so many answers for this, but my problem is different, I want to accept the URL with all below formats:

```
http://www.sample.com
https://www.sample.com
http://www.sample.com/xyz
www.sample.com
www.sample.com/xyz/#/xyz
sample.com

// & much more ...
```

So here idea is, I am allowing the user to enter there website & another user can just click on the saved website & go to users website. So here it's not a good idea to restrict the user to input proper URL, they can enter any of the above formats. Here is the regex I am using right now, but that only checks if URL starts from proper protocol:

```
^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$
```

Comment: Do you want validation for protocol or domain address?, If it's for protocol, check for default browser protocol if not specified, accordingly do validation.

Comment: Actually both, user can enter with protocol or only domain but not just any random string like, it should match those given criteria I have entered in question

Comment: so with proper protocol, if the url contains "sample.com" it should pass, is that what you mean ?

Comment: @Rizwan, Yes thats one of the best and easiest way to handle above validation.

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman also its possible that there will be no protocol, so that should pass as well if there is no protocol I will handle it myself, why to ask user to enter it, some users even don't know HTTP or HTTPS

Comment: Yes true, look at my answer

Comment: How exactly is your problem different from all the other ones out there?

Comment: @torazaburo mostly I have found answers for URL validation and if for domain then those doesn't contain `hash` or `query strings`

Comment: But your examples include no query strings.

Comment: @torazaburo I understand, I should have included those, but those are needed & my excepted answer covers everything.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the regex `^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*$`

This is a basic one I build just now. A google search can give you more.

Here

- ^ Should start with
- ((https?|ftp|smtp)://)?  may or maynot contain any of these protocols
- (www.)? may or may not have www.
- [a-z0-9]+(.[a-z]+) url and domain and also subdomain if any upto 2 levels
- (/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+/?)*/? can contain path to files but not necessary. last may contain a `/`
- $ should end there

```js
var a=["http://www.sample.com","https://www.sample.com/","https://www.sample.com#","http://www.sample.com/xyz","http://www.sample.com/#xyz","www.sample.com","www.sample.com/xyz/#/xyz","sample.com","sample.com?name=foo","http://www.sample.com#xyz","http://www.sample.c"];
var re=/^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,}){1,3}(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9#]+)*\/?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+&?)?$/;
a.map(x=>console.log(x+" => "+re.test(x)));
```

Comment: If I enter like this `http://www.sample.com/` `/` at the last it does not work also for query strings

Comment: edited. please check it

Comment: thanks for solutions, but sorry to bother you again, but this is failing `http://www.sample.com#` also it doesn't support query strings those could start like `http://www.sample.com?xyz=abc` or `http://www.sample.com/?xyz=abc`

Comment: query string support added.

Comment: added support for http://www.sample.com#

Comment: `http://www.sample.com#xyz` this is failing but this works `http://www.sample.com/#xyz`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137319/discussion-between-sagar-v-and-dheeraj-agrawal).

Comment: this does not support. www.google.co.in

Comment: Hi, To support URLs like `https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149` , i think you should change `(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9#]+)` to  `(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9-_#]+)`

Comment: This does not support URL like "https://web-site.com" or "https://www.web-site.com"

Comment: Doesn't support `http://blog.example.com`

Comment: ^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*$ 
You could use this for sub domains or vist: https://themadhurgupta.blogspot.com/2019/09/regular-expression.html

Comment: it does validate https://xy.com.br/\{}<>|`^"/bb also spaces !

Comment: @SagarV : its showing valid even if i just put ftp  or www or smtp  in the text field , which is not valid

Comment: @AkshayChampavat please re check and if you're able to reproduce it, share a fiddle link

Comment: ^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#_-]+\/?)*$ support - _ not perfect yet... working will share updated one letter

Answer (score 14):

You can try this:

```
^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(ftp|http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\/)[\w#]+)*(\/\w+\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?\/?$
```

[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ELjthy/10)

```js
const regex = /^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(ftp|http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\/)[\w#]+)*(\/\w+\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?\/?$/gm;
const str = `http://www.sample.com
https://www.sample.com
http://www.sample.com/xyz
www.sample.com
www.sample.com/xyz/#/xyz
sample.com
www.sample.com
mofiz.com
kolim.com
www.murikhao.www.sample.com
http://murihao.www.sample.com
http://www.sample.com/xyz?abc=dkd&p=q&c=2
www.sample.gov.bd
www.sample.com.en
www.sample.vu
www.sample.u/


`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {

    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log("matched :"+m[0]);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't support *subdomain* _(I should have added that to my list)_ also it should support other top level domains `.tv, .in, .co.in` all this are valid

Comment: yeah you should have :) the base of my answer was to have sample.com, help me define the base, to have answer of your liking

Comment: yeah so it could be anything, it could contain any top level domain, any domain name _(not only sample)_, protocol, query strings & hash

Comment: :D :D I thought you were only talking about sample.com in the first place , plz take a look now :P

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal does this solve your problem now ?

Comment: with the test cases I have asked in my question its working fine, but as I started testing more I found more test cases & my accepted answer is solving all those cases. I should I put all test cases while asking.

Comment: One of best answers here. @Sagar answer is also good but it is not validating some forms (i.e. www.i, www.jsjjs.) . But this answer is working for all those cases.

Comment: It doesn't validate valid URLs if you add `/` at the end. For example: `https//www.google.com/`

Comment: Have you tested this regex by putting str value as "test", url validation not working